# SAX xml parser's missing line number

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I am receiving a XML parsing exception related to UTF-8, and this is the message:

```
Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence.
[Feb 23 13:19:01.937 PST 2015][main][SEVERE][com.accelovation.nlp.util.xml.XMLUtil$XMLDocument:<init>] SAX Exceptoin :org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
```

I am trying to debug, but it requires to modify compiler options to generate line number attributes. I can't set a break point and Eclipse reminds me:

```
Unable to install breakpoint in org.apache.exerces.jaxp.DocumentBuiderImpl due to missing line number attributes. Modify compiler options to generate line number attributes.
```

How should I modify compiler options to generate numbers? In my Eclipse compiler options, I already checked "Add line numbers to generated class files".

Add more details of how the XML file is parsed, where the parameter is a File object passed to this function:

```
 Document document = null;

        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                                                           .newDocumentBuilder();
        if (resolver != null) {
            docBuilder.setEntityResolver(resolver);
        }
        document = docBuilder.parse(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to generate accurate line numbers for encoding errors, because if the file is incorrectly encoded, then detecting line boundaries is unreliable. I don't think using Eclipse to run Xerces in debugging mode is going to help you much.

I've heard it said that emacs is good on diagnostics for encoding errors. Try opening your file in emacs and see what it says. Alternatively, the most common cause of the this error is that the file is actually encoded in iso-8859-1 rather than utf-8; so try changing the XML declaration and seeing if that works.

Comment: My xml doesn't have <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> declaration. it used to work. Now I tried explicitly adding this section to xml file and tried both "UTF-8" and ISO-8859-1, and i got same error.

Comment: Are you saying you got the error "Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence" when you declared the encoding as ISO-8859-1? If that's the case, then you need to look hard at whether it is actually this file that contains the error, or whether it's coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Come to think of it, you haven't told us how you are parsing the file. Perhaps you're creating a Java Reader rather than InputStream, so the byte-to-character decoding is being done by the Java I/O library, which of course doesn't look at the XML declaration.

Comment: please see the updated post, which shows how the XML is parsed.

Comment: Thanks. Does the XML document comprise a single entity? i.e., are there any external DTDs or external entities involved? Because otherwise, I really can't see any reason why a file declared with iso-8859-1 encoding could result in an error saying "invalid UTF-8".